# Collect dates of 2 columns within the same table

Tags: mysql

I have two date columns in my table and I need a list of all dates which are in the table.

I tried it with the following statement already

`SELECT GREATEST(
IFNULL(DATE(record_date), 0), 
IFNULL(DATE(edit_date), 0)
) as 'date_val'
FROM TBL_EXAMPLE
GROUP BY date_val
ORDER BY date_val;`

With this SQL statement some of the dates getting lost and I don't know why. I just want a complete list of all dates which are in this table (DISTINCT, descending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `UNION`.

```
 SELECT record_date AS dt FROM TBL_EXAMPLE
 UNION
 SELECT edit_date AS dt FROM TBL_EXAMPLE
 ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

Union eliminates nulls and duplicates.